# error in linq cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

Contain has error:

> error in linq cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable

Why?

```
public class ListQuestionAssessor
{
        public string sum  { get; set; }
        public int QuestionsID { get; set; }
        public int AssessorID { get; set; }
        public int AssessID { get; set; }
}

List<ListQuestionAssessor> objList = new List<ListQuestionAssessor>();

        var lisaAddAssessor = (from p in objList
                               where
                                   !
                                   (from assessor in ObjNotIn
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        assessor.id
                                    }).Contains(new { p.QuestionsID })
                               select new QuestionAssessor()
                               {
                                   QuestionsID = initQuestionerId

                               }).ToList();
```

Comment: My problem was solved Tanks

Comment: please tell us what happened or remove this question

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem is that you are trying to check

```
.Contains(new { p.QuestionsID })
```

Contains is expecting a parameter of the same type as the collection. and since the collection is anonymous, this is probably what caused the error.

rewrite it as

```
.Any(a => a.id == p.QuestionsID)
```